# I can't format disk in USB floppy drive

Tags: usb, format, floppy

I need to low-level format floppies with an external usb floppy drive in ubuntu 10.04 (or later) server.

I have tried the tools that come with util-linux-ng, and contain (specifically) fdformat.

Unfortunately these tools are written to use /dev/fd* devices, and not /dev/sd* that is used with the usb floppy drives I have on hand.

Alternatives to using the tools would be appreciated (note, the computers I have at my disposal do not have floppy connectors on the main board, so please don't recommend using a "real" floppy drive).

for example, I know dd works to zero the drive, but I suspect I need a copy of a working, blank formatted floppy as the if=  parameter.  I have my doubts this would be a robust, ongoing solution for actually writing out the tracks on the floppy.

the answers are not at:
[How can I get a USB floppy drive to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14733/how-can-i-get-a-usb-floppy-drive-to-work)
[How to format a USB or external drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68809/how-to-format-a-usb-or-external-drive)
...and lots of others

Comment: Have you tried 'gparted'?

Comment: just try: 1. unmounting the floppy (umount /dev/fd*) and 2. overwriting the floppy (sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/fd*). if you are not sure what "fd*" you are targeting, try lsblk and locate the one of 1.44 or 2.88 MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mtools.
apt-get install mtools

Edit the /etc/mtools.conf file to have one of the drive letters point at your usb floppy drive. For me the usb floppy was /dev/sdg (Use dmesg to determine this.)

```
# # Linux floppy drives
#drive a: file="/dev/fd0" exclusive
drive a: file="/dev/sdg" exclusive
```

Then mformat a:

mformat a:

Comment: worked perfectly with xubuntu 16.04.  Will have to verify at the client that actually needs it, using older ubuntu versions.  Also appears to automatically format it with fat12 filesystem

Comment: It did not work on an Ubuntu 18.04 ... ufiformat did the trick ... see below...

Answer (score 5):

The fdutils web site refers to http://www.geocities.jp/tedi_world/format_usbfdd_e.html for usb floppy drives.

Comment: It is packaged, `apt-get install ufiformat` . Then check that the floppy is umounted and `ufiformat  <device>`

Comment: This works on xubuntu 14.04.  Later tested on 16.04.

Comment: ufiformat worked on ubuntu 18.04 THANKS!!!!

Answer (score -5):

Have you tried gparted as the root (sudo) user?  I use this tool daily for all kinds of drives yet I a floppy - I have not.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted
sudo gparted
```

Look to the top right to find your drive.  If Linux can mount it - Gparted should be able to format it!

Comment: `gparted` is for partitioning hard disks, not low level formatting floppies ( which are not partitioned ).